# How do I resize an image in Notes?

Tags: graphics, notes.app

I can't resize an image by dragging and dropping in Notes.

[image]

How do I resize an image in Notes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In macOS, you can toggle between thumbnails and actual size (max width = 100%) by right-clicking any image in the note and choosing ‘View as Small Images’.

In iOS, hold an image to open the context menu, then choose View As → Small. Alternatively, tap the ellipsis button in the toolbar and choose Attachment Size → Small.

Comment: Selecting `View as Small Images`, the image is too small:-(

Comment: This does not change the photo size, only what you see. The Notes file size does not change.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me (and doesn't require any screenshots):

1. Right-click image. Select Open with Preview.
2. Select Tools in the menu and then select **Adjust Size**.
3. A menu should pop up allowing you to adjust the size. Make necessary changes and click Ok.
4. Select entire image (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and copy it to clipboard (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).
5. Open notes and paste image (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)

Comment: This may not be the best way.  This creates a new image in tiff format, which isn't space efficient.  Better to export the image as jpeg, then drag and drop it

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for MacOS

1. Paste the IMAGE in Notes
2. Double click the IMAGE
3. Zoom out / make window smaller
4. Take screenshot
5. Paste it in the original note
6. Delete old image

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible on iPadOS 16 and iOS 16. The image has to be on the drawing area for it to be resized.

Comment: please provide instructions. i’m on ipadOS 16.6.2

Comment: Hold and drag the image to a drawing area in the Notes app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the image with Preview and zoom it. Then take a screenshot with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. Then paste the screenshot back into Notes.

It seems Notes does not support image resizing at this time.
If you insert a photo to Notes, it is always too big.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to take a screenshot and open up Preview
- Click **Tools > Adjust size** on the top menu, I find between 600 and 800 wide looks the best on Apple Notes
- Select **Edit > Copy** and paste into Notes

Answer (score 0):

So far what works best for me is to copy/drag the image into a new mail message, resize it there by selecting small/medium/large size, then copy it again and paste in Notes (or wherever).

When I have several images to resize, I just drag them to a mail message already set with, say, Medium, and drag them again to Notes.

Still, a quick action such as select the image in Notes, click (something) and be done would be better, but I cannot find such a thing.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply drag and drop the image into notes and resize as you want. It's very simple.

Comment: This won't work